# Adding up the sum of random generated numbers in a for loop

Tags: c#, loops, sum, for-loop

```
 class Class1
 {

[STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

   int lap, avg = 0;
   double time = 0;  
   Random generator = new Random();
   time = generator.Next(5, 10);


   for (lap = 1; lap <= 10; lap++) 

   {

    time = (generator.NextDouble())* 10 + 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Lap {0} with a lap time of {1} seconds!!!!"lap,time.ToString("##.00"));  

   }// end for

    Console.WriteLine("The total time it took is {0}",time);
                  Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Slap the enter key to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
 }
}
```

I'm trying to teach myself c#, however this problem really has me baffled. How do i add the time variable each time through the loop to get the sum of all ten laps? any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If I got you correctly, you would need to introduce a new variable to keep the total time:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int lap, avg = 0;

        Random generator = new Random();

        double time = generator.Next(5, 10);
        double totalTime = 0.0;

        for (lap = 1; lap <= 10; lap++) 
        {
            time = (generator.NextDouble())* 10 + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Lap {0} with a lap time of {1:##.00} seconds!!!!", 
                lap, time);  

            totalTime += time;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The total time it took is {0}", totalTime);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Slap the enter key to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for those trying to make it nice, i was also in edit mode...my bad but thanks everyone!

Comment: @Chris: Thanking on SO works by clicking the up-arrows to the left of the question, and by accepting answers by clicking on the check mark next to the question that helped you most.

Comment: i tried clicking up, but i need a reputation of 15 before i can!. So once again Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the previous value of `time` in your addition.

`time = time + (generator.NextDouble())* 10 + 1;`

or

`time += (generator.NextDouble())* 10 + 1;`

This of course will cause you to lose the current computed random number.  Therefore you should probably create another variable `sumTime` that will store the sum of all `time` values.

Comment: That would get you a wrong per-lap time on each iteration > 1.

Comment: Correct.  I edited my solution to mention that creating a new variable would be a good idea.  Like yours for instance :)